# In golang, how to write a pipeline stage that introduces a delay for the next stage?

Tags: asynchronous, go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I am following the https://blog.golang.org/pipelines article to implement a few stages.

I need one of the stages to introduce a delay of a few seconds before the events are passed on the next stage in the pipeline.

My concern with the code below is that it will yield an unbounded number of go routines that time.Sleep() before passing the events along. Are there better ways to do this?

Thanks!

```
func fooStage(inChan <- chan *Bar) (<- chan *Bar) {
    out := make(chan *Bar, 10000)
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        for {
            select {
            case event, ok := <-inChan:
                if !ok {
                    // inChan closed
                    break
                }
                wg.Add(1)
                go func() {
                    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
                    out <- event
                    wg.Done()
                }()
            }
        }
        wg.Wait()
    }()
    return out
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another channel to limit the number of active goroutines your loop is able to create.

```
const numRoutines = 10

func fooStage(inChan <-chan *Bar) <-chan *Bar {
    out := make(chan *Bar, 10000)
    routines := make(chan struct{}, numRoutines)
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        for {
            select {
            case event, ok := <-inChan:
                if !ok {
                    // inChan closed
                    break
                }
                wg.Add(1)
                routines <- struct{}{}
                go func() {
                    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
                    out <- event
                    wg.Done()
                    <-routines
                }()
            }
        }
        wg.Wait()
    }()
    return out
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good idea. The only shortcoming I can see is that if the `routines` channel is blocked, events will be delayed by more than 5 seconds. No good way to tackle that without having a timestamp inside the event I suppose though.

Comment: @ultimoo Due to the 5 second wait, you could easily run hundreds or thousands of goroutines, which would reduce the practical event wait time. Something like this is hard to determine by just reading the code though. Testing and benchmarking would be required to actually determine how things would actually run.

Comment: Absolutely, this is more of an experiment. My intuition is that running a few thousand of these goroutines should be OK -- since all they do is run `time.Sleep()`, they will not be scheduled on the processor for most of their lifespan.

Comment: The only guarantee you have right now in your code is that the events will be delayed atleast 5 seconds. If you need them to be executed within a specific time frame you need a different approach - you also need to benchmark it over time on your production system in a state as it would run with your application (or at least something close to it).

Answer (score 1):

You may fix the number of goroutines manually - starting only number you need.

```
func sleepStage(in <-chan *Bar) (out <-chan *Bar) {
     out = make(<-chan *Bar)
     wg := sync.WaitGroup
     for i:=0; i < N; i++ {  // Number of goroutines in parallel
           wg.Add(1)
           go func(){
                defer wg.Done()
                for e := range in {
                    time.Sleep(5*time.Seconds)
                    out <- e
                }
            }()
      }
      go func(){}
           wg.Wait()
           close(out)
       }()
       return out
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.Ticker`:

```
func fooStage(inChan <- chan *Bar) (<- chan *Bar) {
    //... some code
    ticker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)
    <-ticker // the delay, probably need to call twice
    ticker.Stop()
    close(ticker.C)
    //... rest code
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works with subsequent events? If two events come in over the inChan, wouldn't the second event wait for 10 seconds?

Comment: `<-ticker` should return not more often than period specified. Just try it

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should use for a pipeline application. The context allows for faster tear down.

Whatever is responsible for managing your `in` channel ***must*** close it during tear down. **Always close your channels.**

```golang
// Delay delays each `interface{}` coming in through `in` by `duration`.
// If the context is canceled, `in` will be flushed until it closes.
// Delay is very useful for throtteling back CPU usage in your pipelines.
func Delay(ctx context.Context, duration time.Duration, in <-chan interface{}) <-chan interface{} {
    out := make(chan interface{})
    go func() {
        // Correct memory management
        defer close(out)

        // Keep reading from in until its closed
        for i := range in {
            // Take one element from in and pass it to out
            out <- i

            select {
            // Wait duration before reading from in again
            case <-time.After(duration):

            // Don't wait if the context is canceled
            case <-ctx.Done():
            }
        }
    }()
    return out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved such a problem with my [pipeline library](https://github.com/nazar256/parapipe), like that:

```
    import "github.com/nazar256/parapipe"
    //...
    pipeline := parapipe.NewPipeline(10).
    Pipe(func(msg interface{}) interface{} {
        //some code
    }).
    Pipe(func(msg interface{}) interface{} {
        time.Sleep(3*time.Second)
        return msg
    }).
    Pipe(func(msg interface{}) interface{} {
        //some other code
    })
```